# ASP.NET 2: website compilation

Tags: asp.net, compilation

I have website on the server, which is not precompiled (with source code, so dynamic compilation is used). Now I have new version of website and I want to pecompile it before deployment. If I copy new version over old, all source (code behind files) will stay at the server, so I will have new files (precompiled) and old (code behind). Could these old files affect behavior of website, I mean only precompiled version will be used or dynamic compilation too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, no worries. As long as your application assembly is present in the bin folder, it will be used by the CLR. The old code-behind files will be ignored, so no dynamic compilation will happen.